# How to change classpath without administrative privileges

Tags: java, windows, emacs, classpath

On my current laptop I dont have administrative privileges and was trying to find a way to add some jars to my classpath using emacs or a cygwin shell. I believe i can do something like

```
javac -cp "./thing.jar" test.java
```

But is there a way to actually change my classpath? thanks.

Comment: Just set it on the command line. No need for administrative privileges.

Comment: This is how you set the class path, and you don't need to be administrator.  Change it by changing the line above.

Comment: but would that work for only that instance? is there an eshell equivalent(setenv didnt working, im assuming because of permissions)? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to permanently change the `CLASSPATH` environment variable you can use use [setx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx)